# Where do I initialise the LANG and LC_ALL sys variables under Ubuntu 8.10?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, ubuntu-8.10

Under Ubuntu 8.10, bash shell, the `LANG` and `LC_ALL` variables are not set:

```
user@machine1:~$ locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Where should I set those variables so that they point to `en_US.UTF-8`.  Once that is done, do I need to restart anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it per user in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

If you do not have that locale file installed, you can do it by

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

`LANG` is set in `/etc/default/locale` the rest of those the `LC_` stuff are locale specific variables that I believe are set by the bash. They aren't set by `xterm` anyway. See `man locale` and `man setlocale` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `export` and `locale-gen`; another possible way is to set it with `update-locale LANG=XXX`.

For `en_US.UTF-8` it would be `sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8`